ngRok setup inside the docker Linux shell
I am trying to setup Slack interactivity (handling the interactive elements click) on my backend. Of course, for this task I need to have a https:// endpoint, so ngRok is the best solution for this.
I have previously worked with this tool and it is great, this is my old config for docker compose:
ngrok:
    image: ngrok/ngrok:latest
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env.dev
    command: tunnel --label edge=${NGROK_EDGE_GROUP} backend:8000
    ports:
      - 4040:4040
    environment:
      - NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=${NGROK_AUTHTOKEN}

But now I have a new project and now I am running the Linux shell using the docker-compose, and inside the shell I am running the command npm run dev to start my server inside the shell. I have tried to start my docke-compose using this Dockerfile setup:
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget \
    && wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip \
    && unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip \
    && mv ngrok /usr/local/bin/ngrok \
    && rm ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

COPY .env.docker /app/.env.docker

EXPOSE 3001
EXPOSE 4040

ENV NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=${NGROK_AUTHTOKEN}
ENV NGROK_EDGE_GROUP=${NGROK_EDGE_GROUP}

But unfortunately this attempt was a fail.
Also I have tried to run this command ngrok tunnel --label edge=${NGROK_EDGE_GROUP} 8000 inside the shell directly, but got the error like 'Unknown command "tunnel"'. Will be very appreciated for the solution!

You missed RUN docker command to run ngrok. Try the next:
RUN ngrok tunnel --label edge=${NGROK_EDGE_GROUP} http 8000 --authtoken=${NGROK_AUTHTOKEN}"]

Or even better - try ready-to-use scenario https://github.com/shkoliar/docker-ngrok

You can't RUN background processes in a Dockerfile.  In most cases it's better to run only one process in a container (you should not need to manually run commands inside containers).  Can you run the ngrok tunnel in a separate container alongside your main application container?

@DavidMaze I have tried to do this. This is a part of my docker compose: ngrok:     image: ngrok/ngrok:latest     restart: on-failure     env_file: ./.env.docker     command: tunnel --label edge=${NGROK_EDGE_GROUP} app:3001     ports:       - 4040:4040     environment:       - NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=${NGROK_AUTHTOKEN}     networks:       - local And it doesn't work
